# Android Room insertion fails on testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, robolectric, android-room

I'm trying to perform a unit test using Roboelectric as the test runner and Mockito to mock my objects.
I have my database set up like this:

```
public abstract class DatabaseTest {
protected MyDatabase mDataBase;
@Before
public void initDatabase() throws Exception{
    mDataBase = Room
            .inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(ShadowApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(),
                    MyDatabase.class)
            .allowMainThreadQueries()  // To test insert operations on main thread
            .build();
}

@After
public void closeDatabase() throws Exception{
    mDataBase.close();
  }
}
```

**PS : The (shadow) context provided by Roboelectric is non-null, so there's no crash issue here i.e, my Database instance is ALWAYS non-null.**

Here's my real DAO:

```
@Dao
public interface CountryDAO
{
/***
 * Insert a list of countries in the database. Should an item in the list already exist replace it
 * @param countries
 */
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
void insertAll(List<Country> countries);

/***
 * Get the list of all countries from the database.
 * @return
 */
@Query("SELECT * FROM Country")
List<Country> loadAllCountries();

/***
 * Deletes all the countries from the database
 * Delete statements are automatically wrapped in a transaction.
 */
@Query("DELETE FROM Country")
void deleteAllCountries();
}
```

Here's my (successful) DAO test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@org.robolectric.annotation.Config(manifest= Config.NONE)
public class CountryDAOTest extends DatabaseTest
{
private List<Country> countries = Lists.newArrayList(
        EntityUtils.createCountry("1", "China", "001", "+001",
                EntityUtils.createCurrency("1", "Yen")),
        EntityUtils.createCountry("2", "UK", "+002", "+002",
                EntityUtils.createCurrency("2", "Pounds")));


@Test
public void insertAndReadCountriesTest(){
    mDataBase.countryDAO().insertAll(countries);

    assertEquals(2, mDataBase.countryDAO().loadAllCountries().size());
}

@Test
public void testCountryId(){
    mDataBase.countryDAO().insertAll(countries);

    Country country = mDataBase.countryDAO().loadAllCountries().get(1);
    assertEquals("2", country.id);
  }

}
```

The problem's the Country repository I now want to test:

I perform Insert and Read operations from the database but I keep on having no dataset being inserted.

Here's my repository test class:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@org.robolectric.annotation.Config(manifest= Config.NONE)
public class CountryRepoTest
{
@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Mock
private CountryDAO mockCountryDAO;

@Mock
private MyDatabase mockMyDatabase;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    when(mockMyDatabase.countryDAO()).thenReturn(mockCountryDAO);
}

@Test
public void testDao(){
    List<Country> countries = Lists.newArrayList(
            EntityUtils.createCountry("1", "China", "001", "+001",
                    EntityUtils.createCurrency("1", "Francs CFA")),
            EntityUtils.createCountry("2", "UK", "+002", "+002",
                    EntityUtils.createCurrency("2", "Pounds")));

    mockCountryDAO.insertAll(countries);
    assertEquals(2, mock mockMyDatabase.countryDAO().loadAllCountries().size());
       }
   }
```

For some (obscure) reason, my tests fails. The expected value provided by the runner after testing is always zero, in otherwords no Country gets inserted into the database.

I have already tried the similar workflow with another entity and everything works great: I can perform CRUD operations at the level of the DAO when testing it, and I can also perform those operations at the level of the concerned repository.
But for this particular entity however, it doesn't work when testing the Country repository.

What am I missing here ??

Answer (score 0):

In `CountryRepoTest` you are not testing any implementation, you are only calling mocks. I don't even see a `CountryRepo` object in your test.